# DrawEllipse on Bitmap and return the Bitmap with the ellipse on it

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, system.drawing

I am using a Graphics to draw an Ellipse and I want to return a Bitmap that contains that ellipse.
Does my code make sense?

```
    private static Graphics ChipCanvas = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(60, 60));
    
    public override Bitmap GetImage()
            {
              
                if (Color == PieceColors.Black)
                    ChipCanvas.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 5, 5);
                else
                    ChipCanvas.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 5, 5);
    
                

                return new Bitmap(60, 60, ChipCanvas);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  Graphics objects are not persistent canvases.  They draw and forget.  The bitmap is the canvas.

Try it like this:

```
private Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(60, 60);

public Bitmap GetImage()
{
  using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
  {
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 5, 5);
  }
  return bitmap;
}
```